# Change hash to create multiple jquery mobile pages from one html file

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am writing a phonegap app. I show a page like this: I basic page structure from a html file `with $.mobile.loadPage` and add dynamic content to it. I make the page id unique and then use `$.mobile.changePage($('#pageID')` to show it to the user.

So lets assume I create a page with entries for a list 'a' and then also create a page with entries for a list 'b'. The pages have unique ids. But if I edit an entry from either list, when I press the back button, I see both lists because their both referenced by 'entries.html' in `$.mobile.urlHistory` . I read about the `data-url` attribute and I think it should be possible to set it correctly to distinguish between the two generated pages, but I don't know how.

I already thought about handling the whole history myself, which by itself wouldn't be a problem. What keeps me from doing it, is that I don't see a nice way to override the default
behavior of the automatically generated back button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to change the `data-url` attribute of the page. Thats how I do it now, maybe this will help someone:

```
$.mobile.loadPage('entries.html', {reloadPage: true}).done(function() {

            //The id of the page is 'entries'. Otherwise the html only
            //contains empty divs for the header, content and footer.

            //Fill your page with content...

            //Absolute path to the html file you just loaded. You can get it from
            //window.location.pathname for example.
            var absPath = ...

           //Set data-url attribute
           $('#entries').attr('data-url',absPath +'&ui-page=entries1');

            //Enhance page with jquery-mobile styles
            $('#entries').trigger('create');

           //Make page unique
           $('#entries').attr('id', 'entries1');

           //Display the page.
           $.mobile.changePage($('#entries1'));

           });
```

The whole thing with the `data-url` is explained in the [jquery mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html). It's the section about "Auto-generated pages and sub-hash urls"